# Setar Variáveis pelo Construtor Java

Tags: java, construtor

É certo "setar" as variáveis passando por parâmetro diretamente no construtor, igual a esse código?

```
public class Retangulo extends FiguraGeometrica{

  private double largura;
  private double altura;

  public Retangulo(double altura, double largura){
   this.altura = altura;
   this.largura = largura;
  }
  public double obterArea(){
  return largura * altura;
  }
  public double obterPerimetro(){
   return 2 * largura + 2 * altura;
  }
}
```

Ou assim?:

```
  public Retangulo(Retangulo x){
  this.altura = x.altura;
  this.largura = x.largura;
 }
```

Ou devo fazer um procedimento para cada variável?

Comment: Boa pergunta. Mas tenta dar um new na segunda opção e pensa como outros construtores são usados e pq

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/112052

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim é certo e desejável. Principalmente se elas determinam o estado válido do objecto.

É o caso do primeiro exemplo, nele são "pedidos" todos os valores para que o objecto seja criado num estado válido. Não faz sentido criar um objecto Retangulo que não tenha as dimensões dos seus lados definidas.

Também é ideal que esses campos não possam ser alterados após a criação do objecto.
Um Retangulo é imutável. Com outras dimensões deixa de ser esse Retangulo, passa a ser outro. Então deverá ser criado um novo.

O segundo exemplo não faz sentido, porque não será possível construir o objecto, já que precisa de um para o construir.

Se ele é um construtor alternativo, com a intenção de permitir a sua clonagem, também não me parece que faça sentido. Sendo Retangulo imutável não há necessidade de haver clones.
Fazendo analogia com a String, seria como ter, no mesmo programa, duas strings com o mesmo conteúdo. É claro que pode mas, para mim, não faz sentido dar ao objecto essa prerrogativa.

Comment: Muito obrigado !

Comment: @ramaral blz! vou remover o comentário

Comment: Aproveitando o diálogo, é recomendável ter um construtor que recebe um objeto "y" para transforma-lo em "x"? Ou esse tipo de situação seria mais conveniente deixar em um método?

Comment: @WalterFelipe. Se se refere a criar um objecto do mesmo tipo, o uso de um construtor é a forma mais habitual. Não lhe consigo dizer se é a mais conveniente.